# How to coditionally use PropertyChanges in State?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to change a property of a `Loader` when it is active and ignore the `PropertyChanges` when the `Loader` doesn't load. Here is the code.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    visible: true
    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        states: [
            State {
                when: mouseArea.containsMouse
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: loader.item
                    text: "world"
                }
            }
        ]

        Loader {
            id: loader
            anchors.fill: parent
            active: false // some condition
            sourceComponent: Text {
                text: "hello"
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
}
```

However, when I directly use `loader.item.text: "world"`, it shows an error: *QML PropertyChanges: Cannot assign to non-existent property "text"*. So, how to avoid such an error when `Loader` doesn't load?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I tried a `StateChangeScript` before just like:

```
 StateChangeScript {
    script: {
        if (loader.active)
            loader.item.text = "world"
    }
}
```

However, `loader.item.text` won't restore when state revert to default state.

Comment: You can extend the 'when' clause to only be true when the item is available: `when: mouseArea.containsMouse && loader.item` (not giving this as answer since it might induce behaviour changes)

Comment: @Amfasis Sorry for over-simplified on my problem. In fact, in my practical scenario, there are 2 Loaders in Item, and both of them are optinal, that is, 0~2 Loaders might be loaded. Therefore, I cannot just merge loader.acitve to 'when' clause.

Comment: Yes, kinda had that feeling ;-) You could define your own property in each loader and use that in the PropertyChanges, in the loaded items you can than use that as a context property (see last paragraph before "Property Documentation" in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-loader.html)